# JQuery function not getting applied to every div

Tags: jquery, html, css

First of all here is my code http://codepen.io/akshay-7/pen/Ggjxwb

I am trying to shoot down the enemies, but as you can see i am able to shoot only one enemy at a time.
Why can't i shoot down each enemy? The `divs` that i created using jquery have the id `enemy-plane` but still it is not working

I am not posting the entire code here but i am posting the part which i think is causing the problem

```
var inter=setInterval (function(){
  var clone = []; 
  clone.push('<div id="enemy-plane">');
  clone.push('<span id="health">1000</span>');
  clone.push(' <img  src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130804150458/clubpenguin/images/2/24/X_Wing_Game_Fighter.pn g" class="enmy">');
  clone.push('  <div class="enmy-blt"></div></div>');
  $('#holder').append(clone.join(''));
},2000);
setTimeout(function(){
  clearTimeout(inter);
},10000);
```

## EDIT

i changed the `id`s to `class` but now all of the enemies explode if i shoot down one of them

Comment: @SajadKaruthedath that is really long i can give you a fiddle if you don't like codepen

Comment: With the code you post here you are setting `enemy-plane` as an ID not as Class .... Multiples ID with same value are invalid

Answer (score 4):

The enemy-plane is not a class it's an ID :

```
<div id="enemy-plane">
```

switch

```
<div class="enemy-plane">
```

**Edit**

Suppose you click on the image the code should look like this :

```
$(".enmy").click(function () {
   //get the closest plane from the image clicked
   $(this).closest(".enemy-plane").MakeItExplode();
});
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that if i change it to class all the enemies explode

Comment: We don't have your click code here but it got to be contexted to the image clicked. I edit my answer to show you how.

Comment: @MathieuLabrieParent shoot down one of the enemies here http://codepen.io/akshay-7/pen/Ggjxwb

Comment: Is there some function like $div2.this

Answer (score 1):

you can't use multiples IDs all with same value,Ids should be unique,
change `id` to class

change it every where as `class` in `js`,`css` and `html`

**JS**

```
var $div2 = $('.enemy-plane');
```

and

```
 clone.push('<div class="enemy-plane">');
```

and

```
  var lef=$('.enemy-plane');
```

**CSS**

```
.enemy-plane{ 
  height:80px;
  width:80px;
  left:500px; 
  animation:eny-move 5s 1; 
  -webkit-animation:eny-move 10s;
  -moz-animation:eny-move 10s;
  -o-animation:eny-move 10s;
  -ms-animation:eny-move 10s;
  top:100px;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select:none; 
  user-select:none;
  -o-user-select:none;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="enemy-plane">
    <span id="health">1000</span>
    <img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130804150458/clubpenguin/images/2/24/X_Wing_Game_Fighter.png" class="enmy"> 
    <div class="enmy-blt"></div>
  </div>
```

[**FORKED PEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwbBpx)

Comment: Did you shoot any of them? All of the explodes

Comment: @Akshay check the code pen that i added to the answer and tell whether that is what you need

Comment: All of the explodes if i shoot down one enemy

Comment: @Akshay can you show me that code pen where all of them explodes ?

Comment: Which browser are you using??

Comment: @Akshay:am using firefox

Comment: None of them are exploding in firefox